# Multi Machine Vagrant Setup Only Creates One VM of Two

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

The below VagrantFile should create 2 VM's, however when running `vagrant up` only 1 VM goes up (this appears to be semi randomly selected between the 2). After whichever VM goes up first, I get a message (located after the VagrantFile) saying that a command sent through SSH has assumingly failed. I am unsure of the real cause of this issue, but am currently working under the assumption that it has to do with the likely failed command.

VagrantFile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    serverVals= {
            :hostname => "server-vagrant",
            :box => "rough working RHEL8 Server Installed.box",
            :name => "TEST - SERVER VAGRANT",
            :cpus => "4",
            :mem => "9216",
        }

    config.vm.define serverVals[:name] do |server|
        config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
        config.vm.allow_fstab_modification = false

        server.vm.box = serverVals[:box]
        server.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.gui = true
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", serverVals[:name]]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", serverVals[:mem]]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", serverVals[:cpus]]
        end
    end

    clientVals= {
            :hostname => "client-vagrant",
            :box => "rough working RHEL8 Client Installed.box",
            :name => "TEST - CLIENT VAGRANT",
            :cpus => "4",
            :mem => "9216",
        }

   

    config.vm.define clientVals[:name] do |client|
        config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
        config.vm.allow_fstab_modification = false

        client.vm.box = clientVals[:box]
        client.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb2|
            vb2.gui = true
            vb2.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", clientVals[:name]]
            vb2.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", clientVals[:mem]]
            vb2.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", clientVals[:cpus]]
        end
    end
end
```

Error(ish) Message:

```
sed -i '/#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/#VAGRANT-END/d' /etc/fstab

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:
```

I have tried including the following 2 lines in order to disable the `sed` command from ever being ran to see if that is the cause of the second VM not being created.

1. `config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true`
2. `config.vm.allow_fstab_modification = false`

I was expecting the error message to disappear, but it still exists.